# Set margin gap between text and icon in the Button

Tags: codenameone

How can I set gap between icon and text of the button. Here I've set the textPosition as Label.BOTTOM. Setting margin or padding in style of icon doesn't work.

Code:

```
style.setMarginBottom(100);
style.setPaddingBottom(100);
FontImage bookingIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_FILTER_NONE, style, 4);
Button bookingButton = new Button(bookingIcon);
bookingButton.setUIID("SeparateLine");
bookingButton.setText("Book");
bookingButton.setTextPosition(Label.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special case called "gap". E.g. `bookingButton.setGap(pixels);` or `Label.setDefaultGap(pixels);`.

Alternatively you can use the theme constant `labelGap` which should map to gap size in millimeters.